# How to extract result of Linq Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

My result Expression is

```
 var result = dtFields.AsEnumerable().Join(dtCDGroup.AsEnumerable(),
                                fieldList=>fieldList.Field<string>("CDGroupID"),
                                cd=>cd.Field<string>("CDGroupID"),
                                (fieldList,cd) => new 
                                {
                                    FieldID = fieldList.Field<string>("FieldID"),
                                    Name = cd.Field<string>("Name"),
                                    CDCaption = fieldList.Field<string>("CDCaption"),
                                    Priority = ((cd.Field<string>("Priority") == null) ? 99 : cd.Field<int>("Priority")),
                                    fldIndex = fieldList.Field<string>("fldIndex")
                                }).OrderBy(result => result.Priority).ThenBy(result => result.fldIndex);
```

Casting above result to array or list throws an invalid cast exception.
How can extract result of above expression?

Answer (score 2):

Add .ToArray() or .ToList() call respectively

Comment: ToArray() or .ToList() throws an invalid cast exception

Comment: Can it be caused by the query itself?
For first look: fieldList.Field<string>("fldIndex")
Is fldIndex of string type?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a strongly typed type:

```
public class NewModule
{
    public int FieldID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CDCaption { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public int fldIndex { get; set; }
}
```

instead of the anonymous type then you could use `ToList<NewModule>()` like this:

```
var result = dtFields.AsEnumerable().Join(dtCDGroup.AsEnumerable(),
                            fieldList=>fieldList.Field<string>("CDGroupID"),
                            cd=>cd.Field<string>("CDGroupID"),
                            (fieldList,cd) => new NewModule
                            {
                                FieldID = fieldList.Field<string>("FieldID"),
                                Name = cd.Field<string>("Name"),
                                CDCaption = fieldList.Field<string>("CDCaption"),
                                Priority = ((cd.Field<string>("Priority") == null) ? 99 : cd.Field<int>("Priority")),
                                fldIndex = fieldList.Field<string>("fldIndex")
                            }).OrderBy(result => result.Priority)
                            .ThenBy(result => result.fldIndex)
                            .ToList<NewModule>();
```